# I can not change the BIOS to boot with flash drive

Tags: boot, flash, bios, drive, elementary

Help me, guys! I can not change the BIOS to boot with flash drive. I change in the BIOS the USB to first, but when i reboot the laptop, just the windows starts. I need help! Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: This is dependent on your system, some use F12 some F8 when first booting and there may be others.  Please include your computer brand so that you can get a usable answer.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the boot order in bios to set USB as the first option then  **save the changes**.And make sure that your bootable usb drive was connected.

Comment: But i did this. i don't know what do.

Comment: After saving the changes made,restart your pc.It automatically boots from the usb drive.